# enable bcrypt for Laravel in Windows

Tags: php, laravel-4, bcrypt

I have read the `bcrypt` is by default supported in Linux and Mac OSX. I am implementing a program to use `bcrypt`, however i get the error `Bcrypt hashing not supported`.

I am using Laravel framework version 4.0.8 and PHP version 5.3.5 on a windows 7 64 bit machine. I already have `mcrypt` enabled.

Can anyone tell me how should i enable `bcrypt` in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Laravel [Server Requeriments](http://laravel.com/docs/installation)

- PHP >= 5.3.7
- MCrypt PHP Extension

Just upgrade php